# Автомут в голосовом канале дискорда

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-api

Хочу произвести выдачу мута всем сидящим со мной в войсе.
Что тут не так? Подскажите, пожалуйста.
И как правильнее будет сделать?

```
@Bot.command()
async def all_mute(ctx):
    a = []
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in channel.members:
        await member.edit(mute = True)
    await ctx.send("Исполнено")
```

Comment: Какую ошибку вам выдаёт?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что саму ошибку не выдает. Проходит молча, исполняет await ctx.send("") и всё. Но сам автомут не проходит

Answer (score 1):

Дело заключается в том, что **channel.members** всегда возвращает пустой список *(новое обновление на серверах дискорда)*. Вместо этого надо делать так:

```
async for member in channel.fetch_members():
    await channel.set_permissions(member, speak = False)
```

И, если что, когда человеку убираются права на использование микрофона, то ему надо перезайти, иначе он сможет дальше говорить и его будет слышно.

Comment: Кстати, насчёт пустого списка, да, я буквально вчера это узнал. Приходилось брать в список **member.name**.

Comment: AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'fetch_members'

Comment: И у тебя это срабатывало?

Comment: Список из **member.name**? Да, естественно. Но для меня он бесполезен был

Comment: Проверь, у тебя **channel.members** пустой или нет? Просто я сейчас чекнул в документацию и увидел, что там действительно только **members** есть, что странно, ибо эта штука больше не должна поддерживаться.

Comment: Список channel.members пустой. Бот отправляет лишь [], когда я прошу отобразить список :D

Comment: Интересная, однако, ситуация... 
Вообще, я сейчас чекнул и можно костыль кое-какой сделать через **channel.voice_states**
Он возвращает Map, содержащий какой-то int *(скорее всего ID)* и VoiceState, в котором можно проверить, что если пользователь не замутил сам себя (
**if not *VoiceState*.self_mute:**
    **...**
). Но это может криво сработать, т.к. если человек сам себе отключил микрофон, то он не замутится.

Comment: Если честно, я удивлён, что никто ещё не реализовал выдачу мута всем участникам определенного войса. Я видел тред на подобную тему для discord.js, но там выглядело всё логичным и рабочим. Тредов по этой идее я не нашёл вовсе

Comment: Посмотри старое сообщение, я его отредактировал.

Comment: А, насчёт перезахода в канал для срабатывания мута - сомневаюсь. Я пробовал замутить только себя через бота в войсе. Он делал это сразу, мне не нужно было перезаходить в канал

Comment: Лично у меня так не работало *(справедливости ради, это было относительно давно и, возможно, дискорд это починили)*.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот такой код:

```
@Bot.command()
async def all_mute(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in channel.members:
        await channel.set_permissions(member, speak = False)
    await ctx.send("Исполнено")
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не помогло. Так же не выдало ни единой ошибки, но исполнило **await ctx.send**